# Sum of rank-2 transformations gives all transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove or disprove: Any linear transformation on a vector space of dimension $n\leq2$ can be written as a sum of rank-$2$ transformations.

I have been trying to find some counterexample but couldn't find one. Help me with some hint. If this statement is true then also tell me the way of proving it.

Comment: If there’s any counterexample to be found, it will be a rank-1 transformation: the zero map can obviously be expressed as the sum of any rank-2 transformation and its negative, while any rank-2 transformation $L$ can be written as $\alpha L+\beta L$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$ and $\alpha\beta\ne0$.

Comment: What about on a vector space of dimension 1?